# log4j2 async logging setup

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I changed my logging from sync to async but I am not sure how to put policies on it. I want to apply my sync logging settings to async logging. Please see below.

```
// I switched from this 

<RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${logPath}/log.log"
                 filePattern="${logPath}/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

```
//to this 

<File name="prodLog" fileName="${logPath}/log.log">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="${logPattern}"/>
    </File>
    <Async name="asyncLogger" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="prodLog"/>
        <ArrayBlockingQueue/>
    </Async>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can use the same policies for the File appender.
To achieve an asynchronous behavior for a rolling file, you could use the RollingRandomAccessFile, just like the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Rolling-Random-Access-File-Appender"
                                 fileName="logs/rollingrandomaccessfile.log"
                                 filePattern="archive/logs/rollingrandomaccessfile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger  name="guru.springframework.blog.log4j2async" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling-Random-Access-File-Appender"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

More on this in this post: https://springframework.guru/asynchronous-logging-with-log4j-2/

Regards